# Pythonic way of taking mean of values from Dictionary with Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, mean

Given a Python Dictionary, I'm attempting to take the mean over a series where the key values don't match. The following is an example of the dictionary, where there are N numbers of winner_num keys and the mean is taken from each index of 'value_held_graph.'

```
nested_dict = {'winner_num_0': {'cash_held': 1800.546655015998,
  'value_held_graph': [655.0,
   657.1859489988019,
   668.1170748266165,
   673.4509510481149,
   ...
   682.6094632572457
   ]},
  'winner_num_1': {'cash_held': 2307.4282142925185,
  'value_held_graph': [655.0,
   643.9625087246983,
   714.9614460254422,
   716.9587778340948,
   ...
   713.7097698975869
  ]},
  'winner_num_N': {'cash_held': 2307.4282142925185,
  'value_held_graph': [655.0, 
   654.5754236503379, 
   659.630701080459, 
   664.9212169741535,  
   ... 
   654.4366560963232
  ]}
```

The desired result would look like:

```
value_held_graph_mean = [655.0, 651.9079605, 680.903074, 685.1103153, ..., 683.5852964]
```

Comment: This should be a simple `for` loop.

Comment: `for` loops are completely fine. Not everything needs to be some pythonic one liner.

Answer (score 1):

With Numpy it can by considered a more "Pythonic" way?

```
import numpy as np
nested_dict = {
    'winner_num_0': {'cash_held': 1800.546655015998, 'value_held_graph': [655.0, 657.1859489988019, 668.1170748266165, 673.4509510481149, 673.4514510481149, 682.6094632572457]},
    'winner_num_1': {'cash_held': 2307.4282142925185, 'value_held_graph': [655.0, 643.9625087246983, 714.9614460254422, 716.9587778340948, 712.9587778340977, 713.709769897586]},
    'winner_num_N': {'cash_held': 2307.4282142925185, 'value_held_graph': [655.0, 654.5754236503379, 659.630701080459, 664.9212169741535, 662.9412169741535, 654.4366560963232]}
}
value_array = np.array([dict['value_held_graph'] for dict in nested_dict.values()])
value_held_graph_mean = np.mean(value_array, axis=0).tolist()
value_held_graph_mean = [round(val, 7) for val in value_held_graph_mean]
print(value_held_graph_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way would be with dict.items() method

```
mean_dict = {}
for key, value in nested_dict.items():
    mean_dict[key] = mean(value["value_held_graph"])
```

this will make a dict that maps keys to their mean

or you can do a comprehension

```
mean_dict = {key: mean(value["value_held_graph"]) for key, value in nested_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a script that outputs the mean values in a list.

```
def mean(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

data = {
        'winner_num_0': {
            'cash_held': 1800.546655015998,
            'value_held_graph': [655.0, 657.1859489988019, 668.1170748266165, 673.4509510481149, 682.6094632572457]
        },
        'winner_num_1': {
            'cash_held': 2307.4282142925185,
            'value_held_graph': [655.0, 643.9625087246983, 714.9614460254422, 716.9587778340948, 713.7097698975869]
        },
        'winner_num_N': {
            'cash_held': 2307.4282142925185,
            'value_held_graph': [655.0, 654.5754236503379, 659.630701080459, 664.9212169741535, 654.4366560963232]
        }
}

meanvalues = []
L = len(data['winner_num_0']['value_held_graph'])

for i in range(L):
    lst = [v['value_held_graph'][i] for k, v in data.items()]
    meanvalues.append(mean(lst))

print("Mean values:")
print(meanvalues)
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
% python meanvalues.py
Mean values:
[655.0, 651.907960457946, 680.9030739775059, 685.1103152854544, 683.5852964170518]
```

So this is one way of getting the mean values from the given dictionary.

This approach assumes that every value_held_graph has the same length.

I have also interpreted the question in this way:

```
meanvalues[0] is the mean of value_held_graph[0] across all winners
meanvalues[1] is the mean of value_held_graph[1] across all winners
...
meanvalues[L-1] is the mean of value_held_graph[L-1] across all winners
```

Comment: That isn't the output that was asked for.